# max() function is disaplying the lowest value

Tags: php, html, mysql

Hello all hope you are doing fine. i have been working on a point system where for each message you get points. everything is working fine until it comes to displaying the highest point to the modal with a table. I looked around the whole
stackoverflow but didnt found a solution, The problem is that I have the highest point of 119... but when I use the MAX function I get the lowest value which is 49.8 and it displays only one result .. and also i would like to get a hint or would like to know how can i select other columns in a query which has that MAX() command. Below is my php , I hope this much information is enough! Thank You...

```
    <?php

$get = $mysqli->query("SELECT *  FROM boom_users WHERE user_point > 20 LIMIT 5");
while($row = $get->fetch_assoc()){
    echo "<table>";
  echo "<tr>";

    echo "<td><img class='avatar_menu glob_av' src='https://**********z.com/avatar/" . $row['user_tumb'] . "' ></td>";
    echo "<td style='width:90%;' class='username " . $row['user_color'] . "'> " . $row['user_name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['user_point'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</table>";
}
    ?>
```

Comment: There is no use of `MAX()` anywhere in your code.

Comment: Side note: Take `<table></table>` outside the loop and `<tr></tr>`. You're creating a table for each iteration.

Comment: If your goal is to get the top 5, you'll need to add `ORDER BY user_point DESC` to your query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely explanation for `MAX(foo)` (SQL aggregate function) returning `49.8` when the expected result is `119` is that foo is defined as character type, rather than numeric.

Using the `MAX()` aggregate function will also "collapse" all of the rows into a single row. A MySQL-sepcific non-standard extension allows for other expressions in the SELECT list to be returned... the values returned for those expressions is not guaranteed to be from the same row that supplies the value returned for `MAX()`.

---

Absent a concrete specification, including sample data and example of expected output, it's not possible to make a recommendation for an appropriate query.  We're just guessing.

Here's a guess:

```
 SELECT b.*
   FROM boom_users b 
  WHERE ( b.user_point + 0 ) > 20 
  ORDER
     BY ( b.user_point + 0 ) DESC 
  LIMIT 5
```

Note: the " + 0 " is a convenient MySQL shorthand to cause conversion of character types into numeric type.